# How to discover IP addresses of Windows machines on Windows workgroup

Tags: networking, windows, samba

I've recently switched to Ubuntu from Windows at home. We have a Windows workgroup here that has my wife's PC on it, as well as another PC that acts as a music server. I can see and access these machines via /Other Locations in /Files. So far so good. I'd also like to know their IP addresses. [So, I'm not just looking for a way to see all the IP addresses on my network, I'm looking for a way to tell which address is associated with which machine.] Under Windows I could just right-click them in Explorer and under Properties would find their IP addresses. How do I do this in Ubuntu?

(Reason why I want their IP addresses is to access them with a VNC client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Installed nmap

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Then entered the following command

```
sudo nmap -sT -O 192.168.1.0/24
```

This command took some time to do anything on my PC, but eventually returned a list of all machines on my local network, and also included information about operating systems on some of the machines. (Look for OS details at the bottom of each entry. For my purpose, just had to look for the one with a VNC port.)  That was good enough for me to pin down the machine I was looking for since there are only two Windows machines on our network. For networks with more machines, it's probably fastest to just go to the machine in question and do an IPCONFIG there.

The IP address range to be used with nmap depends on each respective network but the one I showed above is probably quite common among simple home networks. To make sure, you can use the below command.

```
arp -a
```

From the returned list of addresses, take any one, and replace the last part with "0/24". So, for example, one entry might be 192.168.1.23, so make your range to be scanned by nmap 192.168.1.0/24, as in my example above.

Comment: Instead of having temporary variable IP addresses, you may want to consider using static addresses for your clients, most of all the music server. You don't want to run an `nmap` every time you want to find the music server.

Comment: Yep, been meaning to do that for the longest time! Under Windows it wasn't a big problem because it's just a right-click on the machine in question but this procedure in Ubuntu is inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

Commands such as “ipconfig”, “arp -a”, or “ping” allow simple scanning and troubleshooting. The simplest way to get a quick list of IP addresses and their devices connected to your network is with those OS native commands found in the command line.

Comment: one could also look into the (W)LAN-Client-Listing of your ISPs router .. but I'd use the CLI myself too :-) .. like: nmap -T4 -F 192.168.0.0/24 .. adapt to wherever your LAN range(s) are

Comment: Thanks. arp -a  does show all the IP addresses but doesn't show which address is associated with which machine (unless you know the machine's MAC address.) Guess I didn't phrase my question precisely enough. Will edit now. 

Also, figured out how to do this, see separate answer below. Not great for consumer grade users coming from Windows.